# Python: Extract info from xml to dictionary

Tags: python, xml, list, dictionary, extract

I need to extract information from an xml file, isolate it from the xml tags before and after, store the information in a dictionary, then loop through the dictionary to print a list. I am an absolute beginner so I'd like to keep it as simple as possible and I apologize if how I've described what I'd like to do doesn't make much sense.

here is what i have so far.

```
for line in open("/people.xml"):
if "name" in line:
    print (line)
if "age" in line:
    print(line)
```

Current Output:

```
     <name>John</name>

  <age>14</age>

    <name>Kevin</name>

  <age>10</age>

    <name>Billy</name>

  <age>12</age>
```

Desired Output

```
Name          Age
John          14
Kevin         10
Billy         12
```

edit- So using the code below I can get the output:

```
{'Billy': '12', 'John': '14', 'Kevin': '10'}
```

Does anyone know how to get from this to a chart with headers like my desired output?

Comment: You should be using [`xml.dom`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html). This'll make your life a lot easier.

Comment: I need to be using python, I'm specifically using IDLE on a mac.

Answer (score 3):

try [xmldict](https://github.com/thoughtnirvana/xmldict) (Convert xml to python dictionaries, and vice-versa.):

```
>>> xmldict.xml_to_dict('''
... <root>
...   <persons>
...     <person>
...       <name first="foo" last="bar" />
...     </person>
...     <person>
...       <name first="baz" last="bar" />
...     </person>
...   </persons>
... </root>
... ''')
{'root': {'persons': {'person': [{'name': {'last': 'bar', 'first': 'foo'}}, {'name': {'last': 'bar', 'first': 'baz'}}]}}}


# Converting dictionary to xml 
>>> xmldict.dict_to_xml({'root': {'persons': {'person': [{'name': {'last': 'bar', 'first': 'foo'}}, {'name': {'last': 'bar', 'first': 'baz'}}]}}})
'<root><persons><person><name><last>bar</last><first>foo</first></name></person><person><name><last>bar</last><first>baz</first></name></person></persons></root>'
```

or try [xmlmapper](https://github.com/namitkewat/xmlmapper) (list of python dictionary with parent-child relationship):

```
  >>> myxml='''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='us-ascii'?>
          <slideshow title="Sample Slide Show" date="2012-12-31" author="Yours Truly" >
          <slide type="all">
              <title>Overview</title>
              <item>Why
                  <em>WonderWidgets</em>
                     are great
                  </item>
                  <item/>
                  <item>Who
                  <em>buys</em>
                  WonderWidgets1
              </item>
          </slide>
          </slideshow>'''
  >>> x=xml_to_dict(myxml)
  >>> for s in x:
          print s
  >>>
  {'text': '', 'tail': None, 'tag': 'slideshow', 'xmlinfo': {'ownid': 1, 'parentid': 0}, 'xmlattb': {'date': '2012-12-31', 'author': 'Yours Truly', 'title': 'Sample Slide Show'}}
  {'text': '', 'tail': '', 'tag': 'slide', 'xmlinfo': {'ownid': 2, 'parentid': 1}, 'xmlattb': {'type': 'all'}}
  {'text': 'Overview', 'tail': '', 'tag': 'title', 'xmlinfo': {'ownid': 3, 'parentid': 2}, 'xmlattb': {}}
  {'text': 'Why', 'tail': '', 'tag': 'item', 'xmlinfo': {'ownid': 4, 'parentid': 2}, 'xmlattb': {}}
  {'text': 'WonderWidgets', 'tail': 'are great', 'tag': 'em', 'xmlinfo': {'ownid': 5, 'parentid': 4}, 'xmlattb': {}}
  {'text': None, 'tail': '', 'tag': 'item', 'xmlinfo': {'ownid': 6, 'parentid': 2}, 'xmlattb': {}}
  {'text': 'Who', 'tail': '', 'tag': 'item', 'xmlinfo': {'ownid': 7, 'parentid': 2}, 'xmlattb': {}}
  {'text': 'buys', 'tail': 'WonderWidgets1', 'tag': 'em', 'xmlinfo': {'ownid': 8, 'parentid': 7}, 'xmlattb': {}}
```

above code will give generator. When you iterate over it; you will get information in `dict` keys; like `tag`, `text`, `xmlattb`,`tail` and addition information in `xmlinfo`. Here `root` element will have `parentid` information as `0`.

Comment: the xmldict got bug, >>> xml_to_dict('''<i type="all"><t>love</t></i>''') produced {'i': {'t': 'love'}}. The attribute type="all" was gone.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [XML parser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml) for this. For example,

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
doc = ET.parse('people.xml')
names = [name.text for name in doc.findall('.//name')]
ages = [age.text for age in doc.findall('.//age')]
people = dict(zip(names,ages))
print(people)
# {'Billy': '12', 'John': '14', 'Kevin': '10'}
```

Comment: This did not work, I got a error message ending with                   ParseError: junk after document element: line 44, column 0

Comment: Please post the first 45 lines of your people.xml file.

Comment: Ok there was an error in line 45 that i fixed, now I can get the output {'Billy': '12', 'John': '14', 'Kevin': '10'}, but I do need it in columns like in the format at the top, with headers. I think my use of the word list may have been confusing, but how do i get this data into columns?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is an exercise in learning how to parse this XML manually rather than simply pulling a library out of the bag to do it for you. If I am wrong, I suggest watching the udacity video by Steve Huffman that can be found here: http://www.udacity.com/view#Course/cs253/CourseRev/apr2012/Unit/362001/Nugget/365002. He explains how to use the minidom module to parse lightweight xml files such as these.

Now, the first point I want to make in my answer, is that you don't want to create a python dictionary to print all of these values. A python dictionary is simply a set of keys that correspond to values. There is no ordering to them, and so traversal in the order they appeared in the file is a pain in the butt. You are trying to print out all of the names together with their corresponding ages, so a data structure like a list of tuples would probably be better suited to collating your data.

It seems like the structure of your xml file is such that each name tag is succeeded by an age tag that corresponds to it. There also seems to only be a single name tag per line. This makes matters fairly simple. I'm not going to write the most efficient or universal solution to this problem, but instead I will try to make the code as simple to understand as I can.

So let's first create a list to store the data:

Let's then create a list to store the data:
    a_list = []

Now open your file, and initialize a couple of variables to hold each name and age:

```
from __future__ import with_statement

with open("/people.xml") as f:
    name, age = None, None #initialize a name and an age variable to be used during traversals.
    for line in f:
        name = extract_name(line,name) # This function will be defined later.
        age = extract_age(line) # So will this one.
        if age: #We know that if age is defined, we can add a person to our list and reset our variables
            a_list.append( (name,age) ) # and now we can re-initialize our variables.
            name,age = None , None # otherwise simply read the next line until age is defined.
```

Now for each line in the file, we wanted to determine whether it contains a user. If it did, we wanted to extract the name. Let's create a function used to do this:

```
def extract_name(a_line,name): #we pass in the line as well as the name value that that we defined before beginning our traversal.
    if name: # if the name is predefined, we simply want to keep the name at its current value. (we can clear it upon encountering the corresponding age.)
        return name
    if not "<name>" in a_line: #if no "<name>" in a_line, return. otherwise, extract new name.
        return
    name_pos = a_line.find("<name>")+6
    end_pos = a_line.find("</name>")
    return a_line[name_pos:end_pos]
```

Now, we must create a function to parse the line for a user's age. We can do this in a similar way to the previous function, but we know that once we have an age, it will be added into the list immediately. As such, we never need to concern ourselves with age's previous value. The function can therefore look like this:

```
def extract_age(a_line):
    if not "<age>" in a_line: #if no "<age>" in a_line:
        return
    age_pos = a_line.find("<age>")+5 # else extract age from line and return it.
    end_pos = a_line.find("</age>")
    return a_line[age_pos:end_pos]
```

Finally, you want to print the list. You might do it as follows:

```
for item in a_list:
    print '\t'.join(item)
```

Hope this helped. I haven't tested out my code, so it might still be slightly buggy. The concepts are there, though. :)

Comment: all good until 
    return line[name_pos:end_pos], where it says 'return' outside function, when i indent it i get 'unexpected indent', when placing a colon at the end of the previous line i get 'invalid syntax'. Im afraid that's all else I know to try for this.

Comment: oops, made a small mistake. in each of the function definitions, you'll want to replace each instance of "line" with "a_line". Making the edits to my code now. Also, make sure you consistently use either four spaces or a single tab to indent your code. Sometimes python compilers don't view them as equivalent.

Comment: also, noticed that I had passed two items rather than a tuple into the join parameter. That bug should also be fixed.

Comment: Foolish to recreate things that already exist and have been thoroughly debugged. Perhaps interesting as an academic exercise, but almost always the wrong thing to do in the real world of getting work done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using *lxml* library:

```
from lxml import objectify


def xml_to_dict(xml_str):
    """ Convert xml to dict, using lxml v3.4.2 xml processing library, see http://lxml.de/ """
    def xml_to_dict_recursion(xml_object):
        dict_object = xml_object.__dict__
        if not dict_object:  # if empty dict returned
            return xml_object
        for key, value in dict_object.items():
            dict_object[key] = xml_to_dict_recursion(value)
        return dict_object
    return xml_to_dict_recursion(objectify.fromstring(xml_str))

xml_string = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><NewOrderResp>
<IndustryType>Test</IndustryType><SomeData><SomeNestedData1>1234</SomeNestedData1>
<SomeNestedData2>3455</SomeNestedData2></SomeData></NewOrderResp></Response>"""

print xml_to_dict(xml_string)
```

To preserve the parent node, use this instead:

```
def xml_to_dict(xml_str):
    """ Convert xml to dict, using lxml v3.4.2 xml processing library, see http://lxml.de/ """
    def xml_to_dict_recursion(xml_object):
        dict_object = xml_object.__dict__
        if not dict_object:  # if empty dict returned
            return xml_object
        for key, value in dict_object.items():
            dict_object[key] = xml_to_dict_recursion(value)
        return dict_object
    xml_obj = objectify.fromstring(xml_str)
    return {xml_obj.tag: xml_to_dict_recursion(xml_obj)}
```

And if you want to only return a subtree and convert it to dict, you can use *Element.find()* :

```
xml_obj.find('.//')  # lxml.objectify.ObjectifiedElement instance
```

See [lxml documentation](http://lxml.de/).